# Get data about front and back camera preview sizes

Tags: android, camera

Is there any way to get data about camera preview sizes for front and back camera without turnig them on,i.e. opening camera? I'm asking this because I want to know list of all supported preview sizes for both cameras before I even start one of them. I want to chosee right prev size from those two lists and then put it to parameters and then open camera. Its important to me that prev size parameter is same for both cameras. Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
String[] cameraIds = manager.getCameraIdList();    
CameraCharacteristics character = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraIds[0]);
StreamConfigurationMap map = character.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
Size[] previewSizes = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class);
```

get preview size in android.hardware.camera2.

Comment: Unfortenately Camera Manager cannot be resolved to a type. Neither StreamConfigurationMap and CameraCharacteristics. Don't know why...

Comment: @Kapljica you need to be on API level 21 and above to use the Camera2 APIs.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to get data about camera preview sizes for front and back camera without turnig them on,i.e. opening camera?

Not with the original `android.hardware.Camera` API. I have not yet played with Android 5.0's new `android.hardware.camera2` classes to see if there is a way to do this.

> Its important to me that prev size parameter is same for both cameras.

There is no requirement that a device have two cameras, or that if it does, that there is a matching preview size for those two cameras.